# How can i wrap a gridview into a container with curved edges in Flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

i'm a beginner in flutter and still trying to figure my way around. So i'm trying to build this app(i attached the image below), but I'm finding it difficult to get the gridview into a container and curve the edges of the container or include a border. I tried using Flexible instead to wrap the gridview, but i can't curve the edges with that or put a border.

````
import 'package:general_quizz/models/first_screen_data.dart';
import 'package:general_quizz/widgets/sectionBoxed.dart';

class Sections extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('quizz app'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 200,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
              child: Text('Quizz app')),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color:Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                topRight: Radius.circular(50),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
            child: GridView(
              children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
                  .map(
                    (catData) => SectionBoxed(
                      catData.title,
                      catData.color,
                      catData.id,
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```

This is what I'm trying to recreate. [this][1]


  [I'm trying to recreate this][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSl11.jpg
  [2]: ![]https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fWCz.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `Container` widget like this:

```
         Container(
          child:...,
height:200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
          )),
        );
```

Comment: using the container isnt the problem, the problem is how do i place the gridview into the container. Every time i try to use the grid view inside of the container , i get an error.

Comment: Use grid view inside the container and you have to use `height` inside the container.. again see my answer.